# Por que do; Warning array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in /var/www/html/serie/editor_temporada/Make.php on line 83?

Tags: php

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Por que esse trecho `array_push($valorDeLinks[$i], $getValueLinks);` me retorna uma warning?

> array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in /var/www/html/serie/editor_temporada/Make.php on line 83

```
63    //Obtendo valor de links-----------------------------------------------
64    $valorDeLinks = array();
65    $urlDeLinks = array();
66    
67    for ($i = 0; $i < $nomeDasTabelas['value']; $i ++) {
68        $getValueLinks = 0;
69    
70        $obtendo = mysqli_query($conect, "SELECT * FROM $nomeDasTabelas[$i]");
71        if ($obtendo != true) {
72            $log = $log . "<script>console.log('Falha ao consultar a DATABASE -Obtendo tabelas da serie-)</script>";
73        } else {
74            $urlDeLinks[$i] = array();
75            $valorDeLinks[$i] = 0;
76            
77            while ($dados = $obtendo->fetch_array()) {
78                
79                array_push($urlDeLinks[$i], $dados['link']);
80                $getValueLinks ++;
81            }
82            var_dump($valorDeLinks[$i]);
83            array_push($valorDeLinks[$i], $getValueLinks);
84        }
85    }
86    print_r($urlDeLinks); //OK
87    print_r($valorDeLinks); //array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in /var/www/html/serie/editor_temporada/Make.php on line
```

Comment: Porquê o `$i` aqui `$urlDeLinks[$i]`? Devia ser somente `array_push($urlDeLinks, $dados['link']);`

Comment: Nossa pode crê, eu à confundi com uma array.
Então não preciso inicializa-la com `$valorDeLinks[$i] = 0;` ?

Comment: Já estás a inicializar com `$urlDeLinks = array();`, a não ser que queiras ter arrays dentro de arrays.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Funcionou como querias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não precisa colocar o índice quando usar a função `array_push`. Basta dizer em qual variável está o seu *array*:

```
array_push($valorDeLinks, $getValueLinks);
```